# ubuntu server missing time zone in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, timezone

in the rails console, on one server i get

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name).select{|x| x.downcase.include? "east"}
 => ["Indiana (East)"]
```

But in another I get

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name).select{|x| x.downcase.include? "east"}
 => ["Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "Indiana (East)"]
```

What is the determinant of the available time zones in a Rails app?

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: The source code is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb), and both of those two time zones were added at the same time [in the original commit in 2005](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6329daf5acc8f5f2f040cf46f33098fb21a622b5/activerecord/lib/active_record/values/time_zone.rb#L91).  So the only thing I can think of is that the first system is running a custom build.

Comment: Either way, you should prefer [standard tzdb identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) like `America/New_York` or `America/Indiana/Indianapolis`, rather than Rails's weird mapping.  See the section on "Rails Time Zone Identifiers" towards the bottom of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).